# Python 3.x and printing Unicode symbols

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Hi
i'm trying to print out some unicode symbols, lets say from U+2660 to U+2667.
With one there's no problem, I just write:

```
print('\u2660')
```

but when I want to print set of symbols in loop (or one, but dependent from variable), something like that doesn't work:

```
for i in range(2660, 2668):
    print('\u{}'.format(i))
```

I thought Python would execute .format function first and replace {} with number, and then look what is inside quotes and print it. It doesn't, and I don't understand why. :)
Please help,
TIA
wiktor

Comment: The `'\u'` escape happens *when* Python parses/evaluates the string literal. This is *before* `format` can even be called upon the resulting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing of the Unicode escape is done at compile-time, not runtime.

```
for i in range(0x2660, 0x2668):
    print(chr(i))
```

Comment: Wow, guys, You're faster than light. :) Thank You @Ignacio and @user2864740. That explained everything. I redesigned my script and now it uses `chr(hex_num)` instead of `'\uhex_num'`. Problem solved!